# React-native Component Life cycle call Android Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-navigation

Since React Native uses only one Activity for the entire application,  I want to be able to track the component events ComponentDidMount and ComponentWillUnmount,  ComponentWillUnmount via Android Java code in ReactAndroid library.  However I can't seem to find where the component events calls the Native code, does anyone know if it does at all?